# Where do these two lines intersect?

Tags: geometry

So I'd like to know if I've done this the right way or not.

Two polar lines

$ r^{2} $ = 2 sin $ \theta $, and..

r = 2 cos $ \theta $

Answer :

$ (2cosx)^{2} $ = 2 sin 2x

4 $ cos ^{2} $x = 2 sin 2x

4 $ cos^{2} $x = 4 sin x cos x

$ cos^{2} $ x = sin x cos x

cos x = sin x

So there is one point of intersection, and that is x = $ \pi $/4

Answer (score 1):

$$(2\cos \theta)^2 = 2\sin \theta$$
$$4(1-\sin^2 \theta) = 2\sin \theta$$
$$2\sin^2 \theta + \sin \theta -2 = 0$$
You can get the value of $\sin \theta$ after solving this quadratic equation. Once you get the value of $\sin \theta$, you can substitute it in the first equation and get the value of $r$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $\cos\theta=\dfrac2r>0$

Now, $$(2\cos\theta)^2=2\sin\theta\iff4(1-\sin^2\theta)=2\sin\theta\iff2\sin^2\theta+\sin\theta-2=0$$

$$\implies\sin\theta=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{17}}4$$

But $\sqrt{17}>4\implies-1-\sqrt{17}<-5\implies\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{17}}4<-1$

But for real $\theta,-1\le\sin\theta\le1$